# What does $|D|$ means if $D=\{(x,y)\in N\}$

Tags: calculus, notation, machine-learning

Suppose $D$ is a set of pairs:
$$D=\{(\boldsymbol {x},y)\in N\}$$ where $N$ is another set, $\boldsymbol{x}$ is an $M$ dimensional vector, and $y$ is a scalar. Then what does the notation $|D|$ means ?

Is this perhaps the L2 norm? :

$$|D|=||D||_2$$ for all $\boldsymbol{x}\in N$

I've seen the formula used in Classification and Regression Trees:

[image: P]

Comment: Could $|D|$ mean the number of elements of $D$?

Comment: @MJD Is that so? Sorry, I'm not quite familiar with these notations, the formula in the picture I've send has no derivation either (it is given/defined)

Comment: If $\mathcal D_i^L(j,t)$ is a subset of $\mathcal D_i$, then $\frac{|\mathcal D_i^L(j,t)|}{|\mathcal D_i|}$ would be the fraction of $\mathcal D_i$ that has property $\mathcal D_i^L(j,t)$.

Comment: Ok thank you very much!